# How can I integrate text display using Qt library for a GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

This is the main file of my Qt GUI app. I want to add text to ask user to guess the displayed word, and the user must enter the correct word.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/alainthierry/mysteryword) of my mysteryword game tested in console.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "mainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow Window;
    Window.show();
    
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply placing a [`QTextEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) on your `MainWindow` for getting user input? What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: Try using a `QInputDialog` to display a message and have the user enter a `string`. Check out here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html

Comment: I'd suggest adding a `QLabel` to display the text prompt, and a `QLineEdit` for the user to enter his response into.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start by reading up on the Qt Creator documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-getting-started.html

Qt Creator has tons of widgets available to use that allow you to do what you are asking. You can use the Design tab which allows you to visually add components, or you can manually specify these components using QML such as https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html.